# Find who deleted a git branch

Tags: git

Someone has deleted a remote git branch (I had not a local copy of it). Is it possible to find who and when deleted the branch?

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to the remote repository (and it was done recently), you can use `reflog` to find out when the branch was deleted. You can then create a branch on that commit to recover it if needed.

The [gitolite documentation](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/reflog.html) gives some more information.

Comment: It's likely the remote repository is a bare repository, and doesn't have the reflog turned on by default.

Answer (score 5):

In general, no, unless you have utilized the various hooks to do some sort of logging, or configured `git-daemon` to log connections, or if you use `ssh` connections, your `syslog` configuration might have captured enough information to correlate with.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but maybe someone will find it useful
If your git server is Bitbucket server and you have access to the DB, you can run the following query:

```
select p.project_key, r.slug, pr.ref_id, pr.change_type, pr.from_hash, pr.to_hash, nu.name, a.created_timestamp from sta_repo_push_ref pr join sta_repo_activity ra on ra.activity_id = pr.activity_id join repository r on r.id = ra.repository_id join project p on p.id = r.project_id join sta_activity a on a.id = pr.activity_id join sta_normal_user nu on nu.user_id = a.user_id where p.project_key = '<project_key>' and r.slug = '<repository_slug>' and to_hash like '0000000%' and ref_id='refs/heads/<branch_name>' order by a.created_timestamp desc;
```

Make sure to replace the project key and repository and branch name. After execute you will find user name in the name column